# Writing a clearer answer than an existing one

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

If an answer is written in such a way that it is comprehensible, but could be written more clearly, what is the correct course of action for another user?

- Edit the answer to make it more clear
- Leave a comment on the answer to clarify, or to point out what could be clarified
- Write your own answer which adds no new content, but is more clear

Are any of the above *the* correct course of action?  Is any preferred over any other?

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2080/759

Comment: answers may be related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/712/759

Comment: I think it probably depends on the magnitude of the changes.  At one end of the spectrum you'd just edit to clean up grammar and spelling errors that make it hard to understand; at the other end you'd probably write your own answer if the problem is that the answer leaves out all the "connective tissue" and needs to be four times longer.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/554/5323

Answer (score 4):

> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you. ([source](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/editing))

A reason given for editing is:

> To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)

So I can't answer which is the *best* action to take, but editing someone else's work to make it clearer is 100% Glatt Kosher. If you want a place to own your own words, you may start a blog. SE is about community managed and collaboratively edited content.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11474/166155

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you're doing.

- If you're leaving the original idea intact, and just *clarifying* the answer, then you should **edit** the old answer; although if it's too much work, then you can always leave a comment, urging the original poster to edit his/her own post.
- If you're adding *new ideas*, then you should add a **new answer**.
- If you're leaving the original idea intact, and you're *adding sources*, then I think that **either approach is fine** -- you could edit in the source, or post your own answer. (*For example, I edited in a source [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/49094/revisions), even though I could have used the same information to post a new answer. I felt like being nice, but I don't think that was strictly necessary.*)

It's all about maintaining *author's intent*, I think. And, like [Double AA says](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3418/5323), editing is important.